# Gan Eden vs. Olam Haba

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, olam-haba-world-to-come, gan-eden

Please correct me if I'm wrong:

The purpose of creation is to create a בית בתחתונים for G-d. The more mitzvos Jews engage in, the more they are guided by their soul's desire to give as opposed to the body's desire to take, the sooner the Messiah will arrive and usher in Olam Haba: a time in which G-d will fully dwell on Earth.

My understanding is that every Jew has a place in Olam Haba, but the same cannot be said for Gan Eden. Upon death, the soul is resurrected to Gan Eden, at which point your life and every action taken is accounted for. If your good deeds outweigh the bad, you may enter Gan Eden. However, if they do not, you may either: a) return to the world for further correction (gilgul neshamot) or b) go to hell for purification.

How is Gan Eden different than Olam Haba? Is Gan Eden just a "waiting room" for a select number of righteous souls to dwell in before the resurrection and eventual Olam Haba? Do all souls exist in one of three places before Olam Haba (hell, our physical world, Gan Eden)?

If the purpose of creation is to create a בית בתחתונים, it sounds like this world will eventually become even better than Gan Eden after the arrival of Moshiach and the resurrection which will usher in Olam Haba.

I think I'm confusing some terms and the timeline and would appreciate any clarification.

Thank you.

Comment: "Please correct me if I'm wrong: The purpose of creation is to create a בית בתחתונים for G-d." You are not wrong, but you are Chabad specific. Where I come from, the purpose of creation is to that Hashem would have someone to be good to. And therefore our purpose in life is והלכת בדרכיו, to emulate Him and help bring His good to others. Almost every tanna who comments on the big picture gives a bein adam lachaveiro answer -- think Hilel's "on one leg", Rabbi Aqiva's, Ben Azzai's opinions of the כלל גדול שבתורה. One exception: Ben Zoma's "bring two temidim daily", which is enigmatic altogether.

Comment: Hopefully useful nit: the term is דירה בתחתונים, Aramaic for "living place", not the Hebrew בית.

Comment: @MichaBerger The two ideas (apartment/sukkah in finite existence and doing good to others) are not mutually exclusive, only different nomenclature used depending upon the source you are looking at. Review of sources in Jastrow is worth looking at. More than that, the concept of "דירא בתחתונים" as taught by the Rebbe is only from G-d's perspective and emphasizing that by the Creator, the lower dwelling place in no way confines, effects or limits. (G-d is the place of the world and the world is not His place. Also, there is no place devoid of Him.) Is Ben Zoma being enigmatic a surprise? ;-)

Comment: @MichaBerger See for example the concept discussed in Pardes Rimonim 24:8:8-9. https://www.sefaria.org/Pardes_Rimonim.24.8.8-9?vhe=Pardes_Rimonim&lang=bi

Comment: @MichaBerger See also Rabbeinu Bechai to BeMidbar 30:3.  https://www.sefaria.org/Rabbeinu_Bahya%2C_Bamidbar.30.3.5?vhe=Midrash_Rabbeinu_Bachya_[ben_Asher]._Warsaw,_1878&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @YaacovDeane How you formulate things changesno life's goals. A Chassid will value kavanah over punctuality; a Litvak reverses the priorirties. Because one is valuing experiencing G-d's presence, the other, character. A Chassid buys a beautiful esrog for himself; a mussarist spends no more than 50% above normal price (as hiddur is at most a shelish above, shelish milegav = 50%) and the rest is invested in poor people's esrogim....

Comment: @YaacovDeane: Also, I don't see the relevance of the either of the sources you cite. They talk about Hashem being diraso shel olam, in terms similar to expositions on calling Him "haMaqom" but not that our job in life is to make a dira for Him in it. But in any case, I didn't call the idea wrong, that you have to prove it right. Just that it's a specifically Chabad perspective to look at life's goal that way. There are 69 other panim laTorah, some of them quite vibrantly followed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding seems to follow, for the most part, the position of the Ramban as laid out in Sha'ar HaGemul, in the section on reward and Gan Eden. Here is a rough summary, although seeing these sources inside and in context gives a clearer picture.

The Ramban explains that the primary reward is Olam Haba, and the reward that a person receives after they die is in Gan Eden:

> ותחלה נאמר ששכר המצות כולם, והגמול הטוב, דבר פשוט הוא בדברי רבותינו זיכרונם לברכה. שהעיקר הגדול הוא חיי העולם הבא. אבל השכר הקודם, והוא מה שיגיע לאדם אחרי המות, הוא גן עד

The Ramban also refers to this aspect of Gan Eden as Olam HaNeshamos, the world of the souls.

(The Ramban also explains that Gan Eden is a double-reference, and refers to a physical place in this world, as we find in Bereishis, but that's not *directly* related to your question.)

The Ramchal in Derech Hashem 1:3:12 offers an explanation of the purpose of this stage:

> ואמנם בצאת הנשמה מהגוף ולכתה אל עולם הנשמות, הנה שם מתפשטת ומזדהרת בזהריה כפי מה שראוי לה ע״פ מעשיה, ובמה שהיא משגת שם כל זמן היותה שם, מתחזקת ממה שנתחלשה בגוף, ומזדמנת יותר למה שראוי שתעשה בזמן התחיה, עד שכשתשוב בגוף בזמן הראוי, תוכל לפעול בו הפעולה הנאותה לה, דהיינו הזיכוך שזכרנו
>
> When the soul leaves the body and goes to the World of Souls, there is is able to expand and shine with the shining that is befitting it according to its actions, and through everything it achieved while in this world it is strengthened against that which it was weakened in the body, and becomes more prepared for its eventual return to the body as resurrection, such that it will be able to refine the body when it returns to it.

Olam Haba is the reward a person gets after resurrection, and is the final reward given to the soul and the body together:

> וזה מורה כי העולם הבא הוא עולם השכר לאותן שהקדוש ברוך הוא מחיה בתחיית המתים, ואינן על עולם הנשמות שקרינו אותו גן עדן, אלא עולם התחיה הוא
>
> ...[This] shows that Olam Haba is the world of reward to those who will be resurrected, and it is not the World of Souls which we referred to as Gan Eden, rather it is the world of resurrection.

Ramban explains why the body should be involved in the final reward, but this is also not directly relevant to this discussion.

The Ramban gives the "timeline" fairly clearly, based on a Sifri:

> ובספרי (ואתחנן לה) הזכירו כל הזמנים הללו, במדרש אמרו:
>   "בהתהלכך תנחה אותך", בעולם הזה; "בשכבך תשמור", בשעה מיתה; "והקיצות", בימי המשיח; "היא תשיחך", לעולם הבא.
>   הזכירו כאן העולם הזה וזמן המיתה והוא עולם הנשמות, וימות המשיח, ואחר כך עולם הבא.
>
> (paraphrased) In the Sifri all of these periods are mentioned ... it mentions this world, the time of death, the World of Souls, the days of Moshiach, and afterwards Olam Haba.

In terms of the "difference", the Ramban is somewhat cryptic, but he describes that in Olam Haba those who merit it will be sustained directly by Hashem's glory:

> וכן יאמרו תמיד בתלמוד (עי' בבא בתרא י' א') הקדוש ברוך הוא משביען [מזיו] שכינתו לעולם הבא, שנאמר "אשבעה בהקיץ תמונתך", רצונו לומר שקיום האנשים הזוכים ההם בזיו הכבוד, כקיום הנפש בגוף בעולם הזה באכילה ושתיה

In Daas Tevunos, the Ramchal describes it slightly differently, in that the higher level of Olam Haba is that by returning to the body, and refining and purifying the body and giving a measure of elevation and completion to the body, the soul itself becomes a benefactor, and in that way becomes more similar to Hashem and can therefore connect even more closely to Him.

It should be noted that others, most famously the Rambam, understood that the "Gan Eden" to which one goes when they die is Olam Haba, and after resurrection one dies again and goes back to that place.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I like Ramchal's explanation. I connect with the idea of elevating this finite world by creating a בית בתחתונים. Through our Tikkun, we bring forth G-d's essence in this world, which will eventually be greater and closer to Hashem than any other world, including that of neshamot (Gan Eden). Therefore, there is no need to go back to Gan Eden, and it is separate and different than Olam Haba. Olam Haba is here and now, we simply have to work to reveal it through good deeds.

Comment: However, is it true that not every soul has a place in Gan Eden, but that every Jewish soul _does_  have a place in Olam Haba and will be resurrected?

Comment: @user27343 It is a Mishnah in Sanhedrin (10:1) that all Jews have a place in the World to Come, the question is what exactly that means. The Mishna immediately follows with people who don't have a portion - seemingly it is forfeitable. In the way which the Ramchal (and to my understanding, the Ramban) understand, anyone who will be resurrected goes to Gan Eden until then, and anyone who is resurrected has a portion in Gan Eden. I am unfamiliar with a source which explicitly distinguishes within that. (The one exception is those who are alive at the time of the resurrection, but they don't not

Comment: have a place, it just isn't relevant.)

Comment: @user27343 Additionally, the Ramban and the Ramchal hold that Olam Haba is _not_ just this world in an enhanced form, but is a newly created world, which is perhaps created out of a destruction of this world as it is.

Comment: You may no longer call it "this world," but, nevertheless, Olam Haba is separate from Gan Eden according to Ramchal, but according to Rambam Gan Eden and Olam Haba are one and the same. Right? They are "different rewards" according to Rambam but the same place.

Comment: @Y  e  z Rambam does not say what you are stating in your last paragraph in regard to Jews. It must be understood (as Rambam himself emphasizes in his introduction to Mishnah Torah) that everything that appears later in the sefer is built upon the understanding of what precedes it. In this case, the reference is all the back to Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah and the order of creation. The resurrection for judgement, death and return to the World of Souls is only for the the righteous gentiles who observe the 7 mitzvoth of Noach. They are all negative commands whose reward only relates to the soul.

Comment: Jews, however, have both positive and negative commandments. The 248 positive commandments correspond to the 248 bones of the physical body. That is why the reward for gentiles is 'like', meaning similar to, that of Jews, but not identical.

Comment: To the Ramban, resurrection is permanent, and the ultimate reward. and thus olam haba. What he is saying is that a person is body + soul, in synthesis, and therefore yltimate reward requires reuniting the two. To the Rambam, there is death after techiyas hameisim, because ultimate reward is only possible if there is no body to distract us from experiencing the Divine Presence. Thus, to him, man is a soul that during life is a body.

Comment: I would have made the previous comment more than a comment, but I am far from my notes and can't provide citations.

Comment: @YaacovDeane This isn't the thread to discuss this, but Rambam speaks for himself in Maamar Techiyas HaMeisim and it's pretty clear not like you would like to make the Rambam fit with everyone else. Ramban clearly did not understand Rambam that way, either.

Comment: @MichaBerger I agree entirely (though I might phrase the presentation of the Rambam slightly differently), although this is a tangent that is making its way into this thread. This issue has been hashed out in greater detail in more appropriate contexts on this site.

Comment: @user27343 Yes, in Maamar Techiyas HaMeisim the Rambam says that almost explicitly. You "return" to Gan Eden after having left for resurrection.

Comment: @MichaBerger I am very familiar with Rambam’s ma’amar (discourse). And I disagree with your understanding of what he writes there for several reasons. Like with many things from Rambam, he is very precise in his language and can be easily misunderstood without very careful reading. But that subject is for a different discussion. I also acknowledge that many people are of your opinion. If I am not mistaken, you and I have learned together many years ago in my home with others. I hope you are well.

Comment: @MichaBerger One last note, Rambam says what he writes in his discourse is only understood in the context of his ‘Great Work ‘, meaning the Mishnah Torah. That gives correct context for understanding.

Comment: @Y  e  z See my comments to Micha. And for the record, it’s actually a letter, not a discourse.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed responses. What surprises me, more than anything, is the lack of consensus among scholars. The more I learn about Judaism, the more I realize there are disagreements on important matters. In other words, Judaism can change from one rabbi to the next. However, the differences of opinion are much more obvious concerning teachings originating in Talmud as opposed to a direct exegesis of Torah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane For the record, I am used to referring to it as "Iggeres HaTechiya" as my Rebbeim did, but people seem to be familiar with it as "Maamar Techiyas HaMeisim", so I refer to it that way. (And you'll more commonly find it refered to that way online - see [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/mekorot/thiyat-2.htm) and [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam%2C_Maamar_Tekhiyat_HaMetim.2?lang=he) for example)